# unexpected T_ELSEIF in

Tags: php

I'm having a little problem at figuring this out:

```
function myMenu() //Creates a menu with a class current to the current page item
{
    $menuItems = array (
        "Strona Głowna" => "index.php",
        "O nas" => "o-nas.php",
        "Oferta" => "oferta.php",
        "Polecane kierunki" => "polecane-kierunki.php",
        "kontakt" => "kontakt.php",
    );
    foreach($menuItems as $name => $url) {
        $class = 'default';
        $index = 'index.php';
            if ((curPageName() == $url) && (curPageName() !== $index)) {
                $class='current';
            }
            echo "<li><a href='$url' class='$class'>$name</a></li>";
            elseif (curPageName() == $index) {
                $class='current home';
            }
            echo "<li><a href='$url' class='$class'>$name</a></li>";
        };
};
```

Basically I want to assign the 'current home' to the index.php ONLY.
Maybe you can come with better solutions, I'm a newbie at this. Anyway, this gives me:

```
  PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF in ...
```

Any help sorting this out appreciated!

Alex

Comment: dude you can not do echo in between if and else if

Answer (score 3):

you didn't close your if clause with "}"

Answer (score 2):

you have inserted a statement between the end of your `if` and your `elseif` ...

```
if ((curPageName() == $url) && (curPageName() !== $index)) {
            $class='current';
        }
        echo "<li><a href='$url' class='$class'>$name</a></li>";  <====== WRONG
        elseif (curPageName() == $index) {
```

Is the line marked "WRONG" part of the the if? Part of the elseif? Neither? Both?

Comment: Ok...this doesnt make too much sense to me. What is the proper way to doing this? Tle line marked WRONG should be executed if the condition is met, if not, execute the other echo...

Answer (score 1):

```
             if ((curPageName() == $url) && (curPageName() !== $index)) {
                $class='current';
 /*--->*/       echo "<li><a href='$url' class='$class'>$name</a></li>";  
            }

            elseif (curPageName() == $index) {
                $class='current home';
            }
```